# Thermal conductivity of cylindrical Si nanowire is lower than expected

Tags: lammps, reproducing-data-from-papers, lattice-thermal-conductivity

I am trying to recreate the results from this [paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.surfin.2022.101834). Specifically, the nanowire I am testing is cylindrical with a cross-sectional area of 24 nm2 and a length of 10 nm. I am expecting a thermal conductivity of around 1.9 W/mK, however, I am only getting around 1.0 W/mK. The paper used Müller-Plathe’s formalism.

I appropriated the Müller-Plathe sample script (`KAPPA/in.mp`). I am not sure if my code is proper.

```
# Settings
units       metal
atom_style  full

# Variables
variable    V           equal vol
variable    dt          equal 0.0005
variable    p           equal 200                       # correlations length
variable    s           equal 10                        # sample interval
variable    d           equal $p*$s                     # dump interval
variable    seed        equal 190511
## Conversion      
variable    kB          equal 1.3806504e-23             # [J/K] Boltzmann
variable    eV2J        equal 1.6021e-19
variable    A2m         equal 1.0e-10
variable    nm2A        equal 10
variable    ps2s        equal 1.0e-12
variable    convert     equal ${eV2J}*${eV2J}/${ps2s}/${A2m}

# Configuration   
## NW settings
variable    area        equal 24                        # [nm]
variable    nwrad       equal sqrt(${area}/PI)*${nm2A}
variable    nwlen       equal 10                        # [nm]
## Ge Ratio: 0.1-0.9
variable    ratio       equal 0.0
## Temperature: 100K-1100K
variable    T           equal 1100
## Simbox
variable    simxl       equal ${nwrad}*6                # simbox x length  
variable    simyl       equal ${nwrad}*6                # simbox y length  
variable    simzl       equal ${nwlen}*${nm2A}          # simbox z length
variable    simx1       equal -${simxl}/2
variable    simx2       equal  ${simxl}/2
variable    simy1       equal -${simyl}/2
variable    simy2       equal  ${simyl}/2
variable    simz1       equal -${simzl}/2
variable    simz2       equal  ${simzl}/2

# Problem Setup
dimension       3
boundary        f f p

lattice         diamond 5.43 
region          simbox &
                block ${simx1} ${simx2} &
                      ${simy1} ${simy2} &
                      ${simz1} ${simz2} &
                      units box
create_box      2 simbox

region          nanowire &
                cylinder z 0 0 ${nwrad} INF INF &
                units box

create_atoms    1 region nanowire 
set             region nanowire &
                type/ratio 2 ${ratio} ${seed}

mass            1 28.0855                       # Silicon
mass            2 72.6400                       # Germanium

velocity        all create $T ${seed} &
                mom yes &
                rot yes &
                dist gaussian

pair_style      tersoff
pair_coeff      * * SiCGe.tersoff Si(D) Ge

neighbor        0.3 bin
neigh_modify    delay 0 every 1

# 1st Equilibriation Run
timestep        ${dt}
fix             1 all nvt temp $T $T 0.5
thermo          100
run             100000
dump            1 all custom 100 ./output/Ge0.0_T1100.lammpstrj id type mass xs ys zs fx fy fz

velocity        all scale $T

unfix           1

# 2nd equilibration run
compute         ke all ke/atom
variable        temp atom c_ke/1.5

fix             1 all nve

compute         layers all chunk/atom bin/1d z lower 0.05 units reduced
fix             2 all ave/chunk 10 100 1000 layers v_temp file profile.mp
fix             3 all thermal/conductivity 10 z 20

variable        tdiff equal f_2[11][3]-f_2[1][3]
thermo_style    custom step temp epair etotal f_3 v_tdiff
thermo_modify   colname f_3 E_delta colname v_tdiff dTemp_step

thermo          1000
run             100000
dump            2 all custom 100 ./output/la_Ge0.0_T1100.lammpstrj id type mass xs ys zs fx fy fz

# thermal conductivity calculation
# reset fix thermal/conductivity to zero energy accumulation
fix             3 all thermal/conductivity 10 z 20

variable start_time equal time
variable kappa equal (f_3/(time-${start_time})/(lx*ly)/2.0)*(lz/2.0)/f_ave

fix             ave all ave/time 1 1 1000 v_tdiff ave running
thermo_style    custom step temp epair etotal f_3 v_tdiff f_ave
thermo_modify   colname f_3 E_delta colname v_tdiff dTemp_step colname f_ave dTemp

run             100000

print 'Running average thermal conductivity: $(v_kappa:%.2f)'
```

Are there other settings I can fine-tune (e.g., temperature difference between the cold and hot slabs, number of slabs, thickness of slabs) that might achieve the desirable values?